# Parse a rb file for definitions

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a simple documentation generator in ruby that will take a standard .rb file and list all of the classes or modules defined, all of the methods and variables defined in each class or module, and indicate whether any methods are aliased or inherited from a super class.

How should I approach this?

Comment: You could dissect YARD and see how they do it.

Comment: I see no effort that you made.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse-engineering YARD is probably the best idea (not sure why it's a comment).  Alternatively, you could probably do this with the [ruby_parser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby_parser) gem.

```rb
require 'ruby_parser'

class SillyRubyParserExample
  def self.example
    class_eval(RubyParser.new.parse(<<-EOS
      class ParseMe
        def a() end
        def b() end
      end
    EOS
    ).inspect)
  end

  def self.s(*args)
    if args[0] == :defn
      puts "def " + args[1].to_s
    elsif args[0] == :class
      puts "class " + args[1].to_s
    end
  end
end

SillyRubyParserExample.example
```

Produces:

```
def a
def b
class ParseMe
```

Of course, this is just a silly example, merely listing methods and classes.